Ambiguous error when navigating to a new page in Flutter
I'm trying to navigate to a new page via onPressed().
For some unknown reason, it's providing an ambiguous error.
Here's my code:
mian.dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc(),
      child: BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          print("Auth state: ${state.toString()}");
          if (state is AuthInitiatedState) {
            print("Login");
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          routes: {'/login': (context) => const Login()},
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
              style: HelpyStyles.btnStyle,
            ),
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
            useMaterial3: true,
          ),
          home: const Scaffold(
            body: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
            backgroundColor: CustomColors.primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

main.dart UI
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            context
                .read<AuthenticationBloc>()
                .add(ClickedThroughToLogin());
          },
          child: const SizedBox(
            width: 120,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("CONTINUE"),
                Spacer(),
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )

The Navigator.pushNamed is returning the following:
Error
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3  throw_
packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 2690:9                           <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 2696:14                          of
packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 1760:34                          pushNamed
packages/helpme/main.dart 30:23                                              <fn>
packages/flutter_bloc/src/bloc_listener.dart 215:16                          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1594:9                                          runUnaryGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart 339:5                                    [_sendData]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart 515:13                                   perform
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart 620:10                                   handleNext
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart 591:7                                    callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                             _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                              _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7           <fn>

Any idea what the problem is?

This error happens because the context in Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login'); return to listener: (context, state) and it should return to the route context so you can solve it by chang the var context in listener: (context, state) to another name like ctx
